# Geometry problem with twoside and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, geometry, double-sided

I created my first minimal working example for this Problem, I'm kinda proud! Hopefully it's correct. (I had to use so many "blindocuments" to get a TOC with more than one page)

I have a problem with the geometry package. I use "twoside" for defining margins for printing. I chose extra obvious margins for this example.

If you uncomment the 3 lines in my code (and delete the geometry-stuff) latex has no hiccups and always keeps the margins correct for the whole document. If I use geometry (which I really want, as I don't want to be stuck with a4paper-margins, but want to increase the used space on each side) Latex has a Hiccup at the List of figures. (With Hiccup I mean, Latex has the same margins on the 2 following pages, which means from this point on alle the margins are on the wrong side)

In my real document the problem starts even earlier, with my TOC starting on a left page with margins from a right page and the List of Tables suddenly on the correct side... (left page with left margins)?

I would be grateful for either a hint on how to fix the geometry package behaviour. Or another method to increase the usable space of a page (mostly on the bottom,  I really dislike, that there is so much white).

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}

%% Following line mixes up left/right Page at List of Tables
\geometry{twoside,bindingoffset=4cm, top=2.75cm,bottom=2.75cm,inner=3cm,outer=3cm}

%% Following 3 lines never mix up left/right pages, but I cannot increase the size of the page (if I don't do it, my Thesis will look too long)
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{2cm} %% Außenränder
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2cm} %% Innenränder
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-2cm}

\begin{document}    

\blindtext % This is supposed to be my abstract which HAS to appear before TOC

\pagenumbering{Roman} 
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures 
    \listoftables  % Here is where the error happens!

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Just wanna say: I already noticed that the list of tables has an Arabic page number, even though it should have an roman one... I fixed that in my real document already by using following code just before the list of tables:

```
\pagenumbering{Roman} 
\setcounter{page}{7} %% corresponds to the length of TOC and LOF
```

Comment: you are specifying margins relative to the default US letter size. Are you printing on A4 or on US Letter?

Comment: It's A4. In my real document I have [ngerman] included before the scrreprt, I thought that would make the paper a4?

Comment: actually you may be OK I hadn't noticed that you were using scrreprt (but I'd use `a4paper` option anyway as needed for other classes)

Comment: You have not said what is wrong with the output, your list of tables is empty so it is rather hard to check any margins???

Comment: I suspect that you are looking for `\clearpage`  before the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` but hard to be sure.

Comment: Hey David, sorry for not beeing specific. If you execute the code you see the first pages have (way too) big margins on the "outside", till list of tables. After that point (just scroll down randomly) the big margins are on the inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the numbering system in the middle of a document (imho today not really needed and senseful) then you should in a twoside document add a `\cleardoublepage` before the `\pagenumbering`. Without it you can have two right pages after another as latex doesn't use the *absolute* page number to decide if a page is odd or even but the *current* page number.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{twoside,bindingoffset=4cm, top=2.75cm,bottom=2.75cm,inner=3cm,outer=3cm,showframe}


\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{Roman}
blb
\cleardoublepage %compare with \clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
blb
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works with my "real" document. Unfortunately it inserts two blank pages and messes everything up... (before that my TOC was on two pages, next to each other, not on the same page where you have to flip it) Any tipps for how to NOT insert blank pages? I hoped "openany" was not only affecting chapters, but TOC/LOF/LOT as well...

Comment: @Bieri if you use `twoside` then you have to have odd numbers on the right hand side of each two page spread. Perhaps you would prefer a `oneside` layout. Otherwise when you force the page number back to 1 you need `\cleardoublepage` to force that page to be on the right.

Comment: With "twoside" odd numbers have to be on the right. If your frontmatter has only an odd number of pages you can't avoid to insert a blank page when you start the main matter if you want two numbering systems (Roman and arabic).

Comment: (maybe) a stupid question: Can I add alternating margins for printing in any oneside layout?

Comment: So there is NO way to start the TOC  (which obviously is always Page 1)  on the left side?

Comment: No. Not if you want a consistent page numbering system. If it should be on the left it must have an even page number.

Comment: (Just wanted to say thanks a lot to you two! Helped a lot so far!)  What if I don't care about the consistent page numbering system? (Well, it would by consistent, but just revesered...^^)

Comment: BTW. I think it's funny, that everything works as I want it, if i don't use geomety, but the other three (commented) linkes of my example instead... Even the pagenumbering on the list of tables is correct then...

Comment: With a different layout you get a different number of pages.

Comment: That is correct. I don't get what you're saying, sorry :(

Comment: This means that if by chance the number of pages in the front matter are even then \cleardoublepage doesn't need to insert an empty page.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Unfortunately my document is completed and I'm just fighting with the layout... So there is nothing I could insert (or cut) from the TOC,LOF  oder LOT... So do you know a way to force geometry to behave like \setlength{} (which works perfectly as I want it, despite the many blank spaces on each page)

Comment: Sorry but how often has one to tell you that it is a question of the layout not of the commands? You would get the same problem without geometry. Why don't you simply remove all this \pagenumbering commands? Then it is easy to print everything one after the other.

Comment: @Bieri geometry is working exactly like `\setlength` any differences in page breaking that you see do not depend on whether the lengths were set using the geometry package, they just depend on the exact values used for textwidth and textheight , which of course affects the page breaking.

Comment: @UlrikeFischerI cannot remove the pagenumbering commands. Both my professors have given me instructions on how to write the thesis. Both say, that the arabic page numbering starts with the actual text. Not with TOC and stuff.... So that is no solution for me, sorry! :(  

(to)DavidCarlisle  It’s not working exactly like it. Did you try my example? With geometry the pagenumbering is corrupt (for list of tables) and without geometry (using \setlength) I don’t get any problems with margins, even without inserting blank pages by \clearpage. Or am I missing something?
Thanks again you two! :)